# Fancybox 3 zoom enable by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-3

I am using fancybox 3 and wanted to enable zoom by default. After popup appears I've to click on it again to zoom. But I want image to be in the zoom state by default.

- I've used instance.scaleToActual(); option but it only works with afterShow: option

Is there any way to apply this on load??

Comment: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1343

Answer (score 0):

i manage to do by enabling zoom button on default in main.js
then used this code and used anchor class as test

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".test").fancybox({
  openEffect    : 'none',
  closeEffect   : 'none',
  afterShow :function() {
     $('.fancybox-button--zoom').click();
  }
});
});
```